# Finding Vector data that is in the area of a specific value of Raster data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlay, vector-layer, flood

I am doing a flooding analysis and would like to know how many roads would be flooded at certain elevations. The roads are in vector data format, while the elevation information is in raster. What tool could be used to find which roads are within certain levels in the raster data. 
Eg. Find roads that are below 5m

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

There a several ways to solve this problem.  One is to reclassify the raster so that any area less than 5 meters gets a value of 1 and everything above 5 meters gets a value of NoData.  Convert the resulting reclassification to 'flood level 'polygons.  Clip the roads based on the flood level polygons.